# Firebase get Provider Tokens

Tags: facebook, firebase, twitter, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase for my app. I can successfully authenticate users with facebook and twitter providers. I have added the linking the user accounts. Now a user can authenticate with email and then connect the facebook and twitter providers. But I have a problem in this case.

The scenario is, the user signed in with email. Connect twitter and facebook accounts to original account. Then, try to send a tweet. Right there, twitter login page opens. The user did not know the twitter tokens for twitter provider. I need to get custom tokens from the firebase for facebook and twitter. This way its meaningful to link providers. How can I do that?